# How to set fetch data to text field in react-native function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, fetch-api

I am learning react-native and have a question about fetching data and passing them to a text component.
I fetched my data from my node.js back-end but don't know how to pass this data to component. Below is the code that i have tried so far.

```
const TableView = () => {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState('');

  const getUserData = async () => {
        fetch('https://----.herokuapp.com/getIncomePerUser', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: data,
            month: value,
          }),
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            console.log('Test');
            console.log(response);
            const array = response;
            for (const i of array) {
              const total = i.total;
              setDetails(total);
              console.log(total);
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
 <Text Value={details}></Text> //I need to set my fetch data this text component
 ) 
}
```

Comment: `<Text>{details}</Text>` there is no `value` in `Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have an array of values and you want to show them you can use:

```
const TableView = () => {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState('');

  const getUserData = async () => {
        fetch('https://----.herokuapp.com/getIncomePerUser', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: data,
            month: value,
          }),
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            setDetails(response.map(r => r.total));
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);

  return (<>
    {details.map((d, i) => <Text key={i}>{d}</Text>)}
 </>) 
}
```

if you have a single value just replace your text component with:

```
<Text>{details}</Text>
```

Comment: What if "details" is an object and I want to access another field inside this object? <Text>{details.field}</Text> Doesn't render anything

Comment: If details is something like this {field: "example text"}, then your code is correct. Just be sure that is only an object and not an object in an array